# Object [object Object] has no method 'discussionwidget'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner to JQuery & Html. I am creating a widget called discussion wizard. while running, I am getting below error : Object [object Object] has no method 'discussionwidget'

Not sure, what could be reason of the same :
Please help :

widget code :

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.widget('ui.discussionwidget', {
        options: {
            userName : 'Arti Agarwal',
            title:"",
            width:"",
            containerClass:".ui-content-gutter"
        },

        _create: function () {
            //Create the structure of Discussion Widget
            var widgetStructure = '<div class="ui-discussion hGridPx_120 wGridPx_10"><div  class="ui-discussion-header hGridPx_18 wGridPx_10"></div><div class="ui-discussion-container hGridPx_100 wGridPx_75"><div class="ui-discussion-messages hGridPx_75 wGridPx_74"> <ul id="ui-discussion"></ul></div> <div class="ui-discussion-input hGridPx_10 wGridPx_10"><label class="input hGridPx_10 wGridPx_60"><span>Add or reply to a comment...</span><textarea id="message" class="hGridPx_10 wGridPx_60"></textarea></label><div class="ui-discussion-send hGridPx_10 wGridPx_10"><a href="#" id="addchat"><span class="ui-image-addchat">Add</span></a> <a href="#" id="replychat" class="ui-reply-disabled"><span class="ui-image-replychat">Reply</span></a></div></div></div></div>';
            widgetStructure.appendTo($($(this.options.containerClass));
        },
widget: function () {
            return this.element;
        },

    });

    var CloseDiscussionWidget = function() {

    }

})(jQuery);
```

I am calling it from a page :

```
<script>
        (function ($) {

            //Load discussion history fist time
            $(document).ready(function () {
                GetCurrentUserDetails('arti.agarwa');
                Discussionwidget = $('.ui-content-gutter').discussionwidget({ containerClass: ".ui-content-gutter" });
        } (jQuery));
    </script>
```

Comment: @FelixKling [Widget factory](http://jqueryui.com/widget/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few syntax errors in the code, Try

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.widget('ui.discussionwidget', {
        options: {
            userName: 'Arti Agarwal',
            title: "",
            width: "",
            containerClass: ".ui-content-gutter"
        },

        _create: function () {
            // Create the structure of Discussion Widget
            var widgetStructure = $('<div class="ui-discussion hGridPx_120 wGridPx_10"><div  class="ui-discussion-header hGridPx_18 wGridPx_10"></div><div class="ui-discussion-container hGridPx_100 wGridPx_75"><div class="ui-discussion-messages hGridPx_75 wGridPx_74"> <ul id="ui-discussion"></ul></div> <div class="ui-discussion-input hGridPx_10 wGridPx_10"><label class="input hGridPx_10 wGridPx_60"><span>Add or reply to a comment...</span><textarea id="message" class="hGridPx_10 wGridPx_60"></textarea></label><div class="ui-discussion-send hGridPx_10 wGridPx_10"><a href="#" id="addchat"><span class="ui-image-addchat">Add</span></a> <a href="#" id="replychat" class="ui-reply-disabled"><span class="ui-image-replychat">Reply</span></a></div></div></div></div>');

            //Missing ) here
            widgetStructure.appendTo($($(this.options.containerClass)));
        },
        widget: function () {
            return this.element;
        },

        destroy: function () {
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }//extra , here

    });

    var CloseDiscussionWidget = function () {

    }

})(jQuery);

//missing }) here
(function ($) {
    // Load discussion history fist time
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //GetCurrentUserDetails('arti.agarwa');
        Discussionwidget = $('.ui-content-gutter').discussionwidget({
            containerClass: ".ui-content-gutter"
        });
    })
}(jQuery));
```

Also the dom ready block can be written as below - there is no need to use the wrapper function

```
// Load discussion history fist time
jQuery(function ($) {
    GetCurrentUserDetails('arti.agarwa');
    Discussionwidget = $('.ui-content-gutter').discussionwidget({
        containerClass: ".ui-content-gutter"
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks a ton, error in the second line was the one. It was a code snippet, that lead to so many syntax errors. But now it is giving 'has no method 'appendTo' error, on the same line. Any guess??

Comment: @user2614405 made a small change to the _create function see the update

Comment: @user2614405 `widgetStructure` was a string, which does not have teh `appendTo` method... you should create a jQuery wrapper

Comment: Can you please help me with this question as well. In the same widget I am calling a method load but it is not getitng called. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956490/widget-method-not-getting-called