# Jquery Event handler not working when calling from page

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jquery

I have written an event to save the data in a widget.js file & the handler is on the page. There is no error or exception is coming but the handler is not getting called. Please help.

Widget.js :

```
   (function ($, undefined) {
    $.widget('ui.discussionwidget', {
        options: {
            userID: 'arti.agarwa',
            title: "",
            width: "",
            containerClass: ".ui-content-gutter"
        },
saveData: function (userName, msg, parentID) {
            //Save Discussion History
            $.event.trigger({
                type: "sendMessage",
                userName: userName,
                message: msg,
                parentID: parentID,
                timeStamp: new Date()
            });

        },
        });})(jQuery);
```

Page Script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#discussionwidget').live("sendMessage", sendMessageHandler);
                // sendMessage event handler
                function sendMessageHandler(e) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(1);
                }});
```

Comment: Where exactly are you binding the event? Inside document.ready or somewhere else? I believe the event is not bound at all.

Comment: the first function is inside (function ($, undefined) {
    $.widget('ui.discussionwidget', {
        options: {
            userID: 'arti.agarwa',
            title: "",
            width: "",
            containerClass: ".ui-content-gutter"
        },} a widget

Comment: And calling from $(document).ready(function () {)
I have update the code

Comment: FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated for a long time.  You should use `.on()` (with it's different syntax) instead.  Also, are you sure the `sendMessage` will propagate and thus work with the delegated event handling you are using?

Comment: I am using JQuery1.6 so cannot use 'on'. 
I read about Jquery Event handling in a blog & implemented it in this way, Is there any mistake in the code?

Comment: who is calling the method `saveData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like event delegation is not working fine with global events

```
$('#discussionwidget').on("sendMessage", sendMessageHandler);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TQH2S/)

Comment: I found the alternative soln to this, since we are using JQ1.6 & cannot use on. In place of writing it  $.event.trigger I need to write it as  $('#discussionwidget').trigger and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible problems:

1. Your widget has class `discussionwidget` but you are binding with id `discussionwidget`.
2. You are creating the widget dynamically with javascript? May be the event is being bound before the widget is created.

Try to fix both.

Comment: It has a ID as discussionwidget as well, So I am sure about this one. For 2nd, yes I am creating the widget dynamically but I am using 'live' to bind the event handler, so it should bind it. Isnt it?

Comment: No, it will bind it only if the widget has been created **before** document is ready. If this is not the case, `$("#discussionwidget")` will not return any element. You can check using `alert($("#discussionwidget").length)`. If you see 0, your widget is not created yet and the event will not be bound.

Comment: alert($("#discussionwidget").length) : It is coming 1

Comment: @user2614405: Oh by the way, where are u putting the alert? put it right before binding the event. Inside document ready.

Comment: @user2614405: I am sorry what I thought did not help you. Best of luck solving the problem :)